# How can I show all the branches in a repository?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository. How can I show all its branches?

Are the following two commands supposed to show all the branches? If yes, why do they not show branch `master`? I was under the impression that the repository doesn't have branch `master`, when asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160690/will-pushing-a-new-branch-to-another-repository-create-an-upstream-branch-and-re.

```
$ git branch -a
  mongodbutils

$ git show-branch
[mongodbutils] mongodbutils

$ ls .git/refs/heads/
mongodbutils
```

Why does the following command mention branch `master`?

```
$ git show
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

How can I show all the branches (including `master` in this case) in a repository? I think it is important, or else, I will have the same false impression.

Note: the repository was created by `git init` an empty directory, and then I `git push` a branch `mongodbutils` from another branch into this branch.

Comment: I guess ‘master’ is not a branch! ,But still a code version. So they either had to create a new word for that or use the one that already exists —  branch.

Comment: How did you get the repository in that state? Git will only show branches for which there are commits (because a branch that doesn't have commits isn't really meaningful).

Comment: Have you made a inital commit into master? If not try that and see if master appears

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)?

Answer (score 24):

As the [documentation of `git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) explains, `git branch --all` (or `-a`) lists all the branches from the local repository, both the local and the remote tracking branches.

A Git branch is just a pointer to a commit. A new repository (just created with `git init`) does not contain any commits. The current branch on a new repo is `master` but the `master` branch does not actually exist. In fact, a new repository does not contain any branch.

The `master` branch is created when the first commit is created. Or when it is pulled from a remote repository.

Since you didn't create any commit and also didn't pull the `master` branch, it does not exist in your repo. Both commands you listed show you this thing.

`git branch -a` is the one you want to use to list the branches.

`git show-branch` is designed to be used by scripts and GUI tools.

Comment: Thanks. Since `git show` says "your current branch 'master'", how can I show my current branch?

Comment: If you create a commit now you will probably end up with two unrelated history lines (the one you pulled/pushed from the other repo and a new one that contains the new commit on the `master` branch. Read [Sam Varshavchik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161700/4265352) for a better explanation of what happens in a new repo.

Comment: If the remote repo contains a `master` branch then you should fetch it from there then run `git checkout master` to actually create the local `master` branch. If there is no `master` branch on the remote repo then you can create `master` locally and set it to point to whatever commit you want. The command is [`git branch master <start-point>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) where `<start-point>` is the commit (or a branch) where your new branch will point to. If you don't need a `master` branch then you can `git checkout mongodbutils` and you can continue from there.

Comment: The `master` branch is just a name convention. Git works the same with or without it. You also don't need it. It's only purpose is to mark the "main" branch of the repo but any other name can be used as well, as long as everybody that works on the repo knows its purpose.

Answer (score 4):

In a freshly-created git repository, until something gets pushed onto the master branch the repository is actually in a slightly "invalid" state. The HEAD is set to point to the master branch, but the master branch does not exist in the repository itself.

A git branch is synonymous with the commit at the HEAD of the branch. A branch is just an alias for one of the commits in the repository. That's all it is. Nothing more, nothing less. A `git init` initializes the repository with the HEAD indicating that it's the HEAD of a master branch, but there is no actual master branch in the repository.

Once a first commit is made, the commit gets pushed into the repository, and the git branch gets repointed to the commit in question. This happens with every commit, not just the initial commit, but now, after the initial commit, everything is in order.

What you're seeing, with that error message, is the end result of git's current, temporary, confused state. If you do a `git checkout mongodbutils`, all traces of the `master` branch will be gone. Of course `git show` will then show you the HEAD commit of this branch, and no error message, and `git branch` will report no evidence of the `master` branch, either.

Comment: Thanks. Since `git show` says "your current branch 'master'", how can I show my current branch?

Comment: As I explained, it doesn't really exist, after a new git repository is created. A git branch always has one commit. Until the initial commit exists, there's nothing to show.

Comment: Normally, what commands can show which branch is the current branch? The more ways, the better (I suspect there might be some command which can show branch `master` or current branch being `master`)

Comment: `git status` shows your current branch. But since there's nothing on your current branch, an attempt to show the top commit on the branch, what "git show" does, fails in the manner you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

As [Sam Varshavchik answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161700/1256452), you're in a peculiar state.  I would not, however, call it an *invalid* state.

You can achieve this same state any time you like, in any other Git repository, using `git checkout --orphan`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 98 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git checkout --orphan asdf
Switched to a new branch 'asdf'
$ git status | head -3
On branch asdf

No commits yet
$ git branch | grep asdf
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 98 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

#### What's going on here is that you can be on a branch that does not exist.

In a new, empty repository just created by `git init`, that is always the case.  A branch exists *because* a reference whose name starts with `refs/heads/` contains the hash ID of a valid commit.

In a new, empty repository, *there are no valid commits.*  Therefore the branch `master` *cannot exist*.  Yet, you're still on branch `master`.

This paradox arises because a *symbolic reference* can name a branch that does not exist.  `HEAD` is normally a symbolic reference (except, of course, when it's "detached").  That is, `HEAD` *contains the name of a branch*.  That branch does not have to exist!  If it does not, Git says that you are on an *unborn branch*, or sometimes that you have an orphan branch, or just a branch with "no commits yet".

The `git branch` command enumerates the branches that *exist*, so it skips over this unborn branch, if you're in this peculiar state.  (*Should* `git branch` enumerate this extra, nonexistent branch?  That's a reasonable question to ask.  Git currently says no, but maybe someday the Git authors will change their minds.)

To see which branch name `HEAD` is attached to, use `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.  If you're in detached HEAD state, the command will fail (with an error message), so you know that `HEAD` is not attached to *any* branch name.  Otherwise, you'll get the branch name:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/asdf
```

even if the branch name does not exist.

#### When in orphaned state, the next commit will be a root commit

When you *are* in this peculiar state of being on a branch that does not exist, this has an important effect on the *next* `git commit` that you run.

As always, `git commit` will build its new commit's *content* from whatever is in the index at the time you run `git commit`.  Using `git checkout --orphan` leaves the index undisturbed, which is why I ran `git status | head -3` above: the index is still full of all the files from the tip of `master`, in my case:

```
$ git status --short --branch | head -5
## No commits yet on asdf
A  .clang-format
A  .editorconfig
A  .gitattributes
A  .github/CONTRIBUTING.md
```

I won't actually run `git commit` here, but if I did, Git would make a new commit now, using the index contents as the snapshot, collecting a log message from me, using my name as author and committer, and so on.  The *parents* of the new commit, however, would be *none at all*.  So the new commit would be a new root commit.

In a new, totally-empty repository, this is what you want for `master`: the first commit is a—well, *the*—root commit, which creates `master`, so that now you have a `master` branch.  This is also what it *means* to use `git checkout --orphan`: that you'd like your next commit to be another root commit.

This is not particularly useful except in special circumstances, such as when doing `git rebase -i --root`, where Git wants to do this internally.