# how to list all branches in repository (only the remote Repos )- git

Tags: git, github

How to list all branches in remote repositories **git**?

I would like to have all the possible commands for that.

i know only how to get my current branch with this command

```
git branch
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `git branch -a`? or maybe `git branch -avv`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show all the branches in a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161556/how-can-i-show-all-the-branches-in-a-repository)

Comment: Yes it's working !!

Answer (score 2):

Use `git branch -r` to list all the branches on the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

> How to list all branches in remote repositories git?

```
git branch -r
```

> I would like to have all the possible commands for that.

Use `--help` property after the command for this purposes.

`git branch --help`

It displays a manual page with all possibilities of the particular command.

`--help` works for any command in the git, so fill free to use it next time, when you have the same question about other command.

Comment: It's a good advice but not an answer for the question. Should be a comment.

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit, to cover all questions.

Answer (score 0):

**How to list branches in Git?**

**Solution :**

To list all branches in local repositories and remote repositories :

```
git branch -a
```

To listing the remote branches in remote repositories from Git Bash :

```
git branch -r
```

You can use the show-branch command for seeing the branches and their commits as follows:

```
git show-branch
```

Happy coding !

Comment: It's working tks